# Dealloc is not calling immediately after release

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a root view that loads two view controller. e.g.:`FirstVC`,`SecondVC`.

I am showing `FirstVC` as the root view controller when the app launches, on some action on `FirstVC` I load `SecondVC` by removing first.

For loading `SecondVC` I first remove `FirstVC` by

```
[FirstVCobj.view removeFromSuperView];  
[FirstVCobj release];
FirstVCobj = nil;
```

After that I allocate and create `SecondVC`

Now only after calling `SecondVC`'s `viewdidload()` is `FirstVC`'s `dealloc()` method called.
Is this the right execution path, or is it due to some mistake I have made?
The above is exactly how I remove and create my view controllers.

Comment: what type is FirstVCobj

Comment: Its just a ViewController to handle a view with some images and buttons.

Comment: FirstVCobj is a VC? then that code wouldn't work ;)

Comment: Your design should not depend on dealloc being called at a certain point in the sequence.  It simply must be *after* all references are gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i assume it is a UIView you're talking about.

---

- addSubview retains the view
- removeFromSuperView releases or AUTORELEASES it -- an implementation detail you don't control

---

to 'see' it: wrap it in a pool of your own

```
@autoreleasepool {
    [FirstVCobj.view removeFromSuperView];  
    [FirstVCobj release];
    FirstVCobj = nil;
}
```

Comment: yes you do A release but there is a retain/autorelease when you add/remove the view

Comment: and dealloc only happens after all releases/autoreleases are done

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. Is there any methods I could try to make dealloc to be called before viewdidload?(just for curiosity)

Comment: see my edit... that would pop the pool right away and the obj would go away then

Comment: Thank you so much, Now I understand a bit. Now it make sense to me. I upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
[FirstVCobj removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];
```

Check with this might work.

Comment: yes but that type of VC's wasn't mentioned in the Q previously

Comment: yes, thats why I didn't down vote or anything - I was just asking :)

Comment: My application is an iPhone/iPad using Cocoa Touch